# ansible - can't access item in nested list

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in my chrooted location inside one server. There are 3 chroot directories under `/opt/chroot`.

First, I check if that directory exists, then getting all chroot names, checking version of Debian (updating for wheezy, so major version == 7), finally - finding all relevant files.

Next step would be to iterate through them, but for some reason I can't access all items in registered variables. For example for nginx host i have 3 files, for mysql - 2 files, ftp - 1 file.

This is my playbook where last step is failing because: *VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED*

```
- name: ROOT check if /opt/chroot exists
  tags:
    - fix_wheezy
    - chrootonly
  stat:
    path: /opt/chroot
  register: chrootpath

- name: ROOT get chroot names
  tags:
    - fix_wheezy
    - chrootonly
  shell: 'ls /opt/chroot | grep -v disable'
  register: chroots
  when: chrootpath.stat.exists == True

- name: ROOT get chroot versions
  tags:
    - fix_wheezy
    - chrootonly
  shell: 'chroot /opt/chroot/{{ item }} cut -d. -f1 /etc/debian_version'
  register: chroot_versions
  with_items: "{{ chroots.stdout_lines | default(omit) }}"

- name: CHROOT find list files for upgrade
  tags:
    - fix_wheezy
    - chrootonly
  find:
    paths: '/opt/chroot/{{ item.item }}/etc/apt'
    recurse: yes
    patterns: '*.list'
  register: find_chroot_list
    # var: item.stdout
  with_items: '{{ chroot_versions.results }}'
  when: chroots is defined and chrootpath.stat.exists == True and chroots.stdout.strip() != '' and item.stdout == '7'

- name: CHROOT check what was registered
  tags:
    - fix_wheezy
    - chrootonly
  debug:
    var: item.files.path
  with_items: 
    - '{{ find_chroot_list.results }}'
```

I am attaching full log of final task: [CHROOT check what was registered](https://pastebin.com/s4uw9T4X).

I have actually two questions:

- is it possible to iterate through such nested list produced by last task?
- why paths is not available?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what to respond but I already saw a problem that has nothing to do with the question. `default(omit)` should only be used to omit non mandatory params in a module (e.g. `enablerepo: "{{ repolist | default(omit)}}"`for the yum module) . In your case you must use `default([])` for an empty list.

Comment: yep, I'll fix that, but it's not the problem

Comment: I know, but you have an answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why paths is not available?

In your output, `files` in each item is a list of maps. Hence, `item.files.path` does not exists, but `item.files[0].path` does.

> is it possible to iterate through such nested list produced by last task?

Definitely yes and there are several options ([subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#subelements-filter), [attribute extraction](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers)...). In your specific case, I would go for [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). The following example will return what you are looking for

```
- name: CHROOT check what was registered
  debug:
    var: item.path
  loop: "{{ find_chroot_list.results | json_query('[].files[]') }}"
```

Note that `json_query` requires `pip install jmespath`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for that and also for some links to interesting reading about filters in ansible.

Comment: @zerocool: forgot to mention that, if you really can't find what you need in the ansible filter jungle, you can still [write your own](http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/creating-ansible-filter-plugins/)